# cx_Oracle returning varchar columns with HTML entities

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

When using cx_Oracle to query a database, I have a a column storing text as varchar2. For some reason, if I have "<" or ">" or characters like those stored in the table, then  when I query the table it replaces those values with their HTML entity equivalent (ex: "<" becomes "&lt;"). For example:

If I have the following data in my table:

```
ID  | VARCHAR2_DATA
----|-----------------
1   | <span>hi1</span>
2   | <span>hi2</span>
```

and then I run the following code:

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE")
ret_data = cursor.fetchall()
```

ret_data will contain:

```
[1, "&lt;span&gt;hi1&lt;/span&gt;"],
[2, "&lt;span&gt;hi2&lt;/span&gt;"]
```

Why does this happen? How can I stop it from happening other than iterating through each column/row and doing a find/replace?

Comment: how did you store the data?

Comment: I've inserted using both cx_Oracle and using the Oracle SQL Developer application. It doesn't seem to make a difference. Within Oracle SQL Developer it shows up correctly, just not when I query it from python.

Comment: @AlecRosenbaum: I cannot reproduce this with Python 3.5.2 and cx_Oracle 5.2.1 (both win-64). Neither from the python shell, nor when running inside an IDE. Could you give some information as to your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You must have some sort of code that is coming between cx_Oracle and your code in order to do this. cx_Oracle returns tuples, not lists, when returning data. As in the following:

```
[(1, '<span>hi1</span>'), (2, '<span>hi2</span>')]
```

Try using python at the command prompt without any additional modules being imported. You can check to see what modules are being imported by using the command

```
python -v
```